# Signification de « ou à défaut l'année »

Tags: locutions

[image]

Quelle est la signification de « ou à défaut l'année » dans ce contexte (ligne 10) ?

Comment: Si tu veux remplir le formulaire tout de suite, “à défaut” veut dire “s'il n'y en a pas”, “si elle est inconnue” (ce qui est bien sûr rarement le cas pour les gens en provenance d'Europe). Je laisse à quelqu'un le soin d'élaborer une réponse un peu plus fournie.

Comment: J'espère avoir pris où faut-il mettre les guillemets:-)! Je te remercie de ton commentaire-réponse !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sur les formulaires et suite à des éléments dans des liste « à défaut » signifie « si la chose dont il vient d'être question manque » ; dans le présent cas il n'est pas clair s'il s'agit de la date complète et de la nationalité ou seulement de la date de naissance, bien qu'il soit pratiquement inconcevable de ne pas avoir de nationalité ou de ne pas la connaitre. En tout cas on peut conclure qu'il s'agit au moins d'un défaut de date de naissance complète mais dans laquelle l'année doit être connue ; si l'année n'est pas connue non plus, il semble qu'il ne soit pas possible de faire la demande et qu'il faille se renseigner pour obtenir des directives sur la marche à suivre dans ce cas particulier.

Le mot « défaut » signifie selon the TLFi « absence d'une chose ou d'une personne dont la présence serait nécessaire ou souhaitable (généralement pour former un ensemble cohérent) ». Il faut utiliser la préposition « de » lorsque il est utilisé avec un autre nom en complément :

- un défaut d'approvisionnement, le défaut de papier en règle, défaut de présentation de permis de conduire lors d'un contrôle, défaut d'obtempérer à l'injonction d'un magistrat,…

La locution « **à/au défaut de** (qqc., qqn) » signifie « **en l'absence de** » ; un synonyme ou quasi-synonyme est « **faute de** ».« **À défaut** » est utilisé de façon elliptique à la place de « à défaut de » lorsque l'on ne veut pas répéter la chose en question.

- Munissez-vous de votre carte d'identité, à défaut votre passeport.

Le sens e plus courant de « **défaut** » de nos jours est le sens « II » du TLFi : [par référence à des critères qualitatifs marquant un écart généralement occasionnel par rapport à une norme de perfection, à une attente légitime] Imperfection d'une chose ou d'une personne, résultant de l'absence de certaines qualités ou d'un manquement à certaines règles et conventions.

Comment: *dans le présent cas il n'est pas clair s'il s'agit de la date complète et de la nationalité ou seulement de la date de naissance* ?!

Comment: @jlliagre Ça ne dit pas à défaut de quelque chose en particulier et ça se trouve après « nationalité ». Ce n'est pas précis ;  il pourrait exister des personnes sans nationalité ; on parlait même en France, il y a quelques temps de déchoir certaines personnes de leur nationalité.

Comment: J'ai bien peur qu'il n'y ait que toi pour penser qu'un champs se trouvant sous la date de naissance et qui indique que son interprétation conduit à une date puisse aussi concerner un champs qui n'a rien à voir avec une année ou une date. D'autre part, quelqu'un qui est a été déchu de sa nationalité ou qui n'en a jamais eu commencera par faire les démarches afin d'obtenir le statut d'apatride avant de pouvoir déposer un dossier de naturalisation, puisque c'est de ça qu'il s'agit ici.